# Argparse - different required parameters depnding on flag provided

Tags: python, argparse

I wrote a tool in bash that I am trying to convert to python for the sake of expanding my skills beyond beginner but am hitting a snag due to the way I originally formatted the command.

The tool restarts a service on a bunch of servers in a cluster that are usually named HOSTNAME01-08 so the original tool takes a hostname, cluster range, service, and action:

`$ prog.sh  hostname cluster_range httpd status (ex. of range would be 01-04)`

It also has a second function that will do a port check only

`$ prog.sh -p port_number hostname cluster_range`

The second commmand does not require the arguments of service and action. This is where I am hitting my issue.

In converting it to python I am trying to use argparse for all the options and commands as I really like its ability to output clean usage and help information but the second function of the original tool is making this a bit harder.

Using argparse if i set the '-p' flag that works fine and all, but its still requring the last two arguments that are not needed or it fails with "too few arguments"

I thought maybe subparsers would be the way to go, but subparsers don't seem to work with flag style names (think i read somewhere it strips it?). The other issue is if I create the subparser for '-p' even with a proper name (say portcheck) it will only work if I create a subparser for the other task as well (call it main-task), it wont accept having base arguments for the main parser and separate arguments for just the subparser. So i would be forced to use commands like

```
$ prog.py  main-task  hostname  range  service  action
$ prog.py  portcheck  port_num  hostname  range
```

Is there a way to use the optional '-p' flag and trigger it to not need the other two arguments? The best solution I can think of is to check for the -p flag and if true to set those two variables to empty strings, is it possible to adjust those arg values in an if statement? I could set those two arguments to default as empty to start with but then I couldn't error check if they don't provide all the arguments for the base function defeating the purpose of argparse. I originally started using sys.argv but was thinking argparse would be more pythonic and a good lesson to try as a beginner. Perhaps sys.argv may be the best way to go?

argparse code I currently have:

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(
    usage=None,
    formatter_class=argparse.RawDescriptionHelpFormatter,
    description=textwrap.dedent('''\
    Usage:
    drtt BASE-HOSTNAME  CLS-RANGE  SERVICE  ACTION
    ex. drtt HOSTNAME 01-08 sshd status

    For port check only:
    drtt [-p, --port-number] PORT-NUMBER  BASE-HOSTNAME  CLS-RANGE
    ex. drtt -p 1234 HOSTNAME 01-08'''))

parser.add_argument('base_hostname', help='Host name only')
parser.add_argument('--port-number', '-p', type=int, metavar='PORT-NUMBER', help="Port number to check if listening")
parser.add_argument('cls_range', help='Number of hosts in cluster (written as start-finish ex. 01-16)')
parser.add_argument('service', help='Service/Process to perform an action on')
parser.add_argument('action', help='start, stop status or restart')
args = parser.parse_args()
```

Sorry for the wordy post

Comment: Maybe I am misunderstanding your question. But I think you already have hit on the correct answer.  when you had prog.py  main-task and prog.py  portcheck, that's certainly how most other command line tools work, for example git.

Comment: Simpler parsers handle the flagged arguments by name, and treat everything else as a list of extras which you parser yourself.  You can approximate that with `parse_known_args` and variable `nargs` (like `*` and '?').  But you loose that expressiveness of the help.  `-p` cannot alter the `requiredness` of positionals.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the [`nargs`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#nargs) of the last two arguments to `'?'` (0 or 1) and manually check that they are both present if `-p` is not:

```
if args.port_number is None and (args.service is None or args.action is None):
    parser.print_help()
    parser.error("Missing mandatory arguments sevice and action")
```

Comment: That actually works perfectly, thank you! Only issue now is i get some extra usage output when it hits the error:  
`usage: argcheck.py [-h] [--port-number PORT-NUMBER]           base_hostname cls_range [service] [action]`  
---TRUNCATED, it shows my help screen info here---  
`usage: argcheck.py [-h] [--port-number PORT-NUMBER]                      base_hostname cls_range [service] [action]  
argcheck.py: error: Missing mandatory arguments sevice and action`  
Any way to set it to only print my custom usage instead of the other usage when it fails?

Comment: @Tony I'm not sure to understand what you mean. You can start by removing the call to `print_help` to avoid redundancy.

Comment: OK great I'll play around with it but thanks for helping me solve my issue!

Comment: @Tony Not sure if I should also add it to the answer since the question is specifically about `argparse`. But you might also want to check out [`docopt`](https://github.com/docopt/docopt) that build a parser based on your documented usage. It should handle your specific case better than `argparse`.